# Get the Count of sign change By End of The Day

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have a Df like this

```
      Date            amount
 0  2021-06-18          14
 1  2021-06-19          -8
 2  2021-06-19           9
 3  2021-06-21         -17
 4  2021-07-02          -8
 5  2021-07-05          77            
 6  2021-07-06         -10
 7  2021-08-02         -78
 8  2021-08-06          77            
 9  2021-07-08          10
```

I want

```
count =  {{"June-2021": 1},{"July-2021" : 2},{"Aug-2021" : 1}}
```

I want a count of sign change in amount, but if the same date are present multiple time then count only last date of amount means on "2021-06-19" two amount present "-8" and "9" then consider only "9" because this is last entry of the Date

and I tried with

```
count = (df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%b-%Y'), sort=False)['amount']
           .agg(lambda x: (x.mul(x.shift()) < 0).sum())
           .to_dict()
        )
```

but not work for multiple same Date amount

```
Note: The last Date of each month and first date of next month is different than count as  in different count
```

Comment: Why is July 2 times and not 3?

Comment: Because the Last Date of June and the First Date of July Same sign in amount both are Minus value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is first remove duplicates per `Date` and then remove consecutive `sign` values:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['sign'] = np.sign(df['amount'])
df['per'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%b-%Y')

df1 = df.sort_values('Date').drop_duplicates('Date', keep='last').copy()

mask = df1['sign'].ne(df1['sign'].shift())



counts= (df1[mask].groupby('per', sort=False)['sign']
            .agg(lambda x: (x.mul(x.shift()) < 0).sum())
            .to_dict()
        )
print (counts)
{'Jun-2021': 1, 'Jul-2021': 2, 'Aug-2021': 1}
```

Comment: Hello, Jul-2021 :3 is wrong because the Last Date of June is the Same as July First Date So, Does not count in the change count,  I want Jul-2021 count 2

Comment: @jainamshah - What means `Last Date of June is Same as July First` ? Do you think sign?

Comment: Amount Sign, both are minus value so no change in count

Comment: @jainamshah - So here is count June - `14`, July - `77, 10`, and August `10` ?

Comment: The last date of each month amount and first date of next month amount is different than count as  in different count

Comment: {'Jun-2021': 1, 'Jul-2021': 2, 'Aug-2021': 1} i want like this

Comment: @jainamshah I know, but I ask what values are counts?

Comment: in june amount counted 14,8,-17
in July amount counted -8,10,10
in Aug amount counted -78,77

Comment: @jainamshah - Are you sure? Not missing some `-` like `-8` for June, `-10` for Juky?

Comment: Yes Sorry    ...june 14,9,-17
july -8,77,-10,10
aug  -78,77

Comment: Can you please Help @ jezrael

Comment: @jainamshah - OK, but whcih values are counts from `june 14,9,-17 july -8,77,-10,10 aug -78,77` ? Which numbers?

Comment: for the 2021-06-18  - ->  14 , 2021-06-19 --> 9, 2021-06-21 --> 21 ,
2021-07-02 --> -8 , 2021-07-05 -->77 , 2021-07-6 -->-10 , 2021-07-08 --> 10 
2021-08-02 --> -78 , 2021-08-06 --> 77

Comment: @jainamshah - Not count `2021-07-02 --> -8` because same sign `-17` In July?

Comment: @jainamshah - OK, so can you change data for see why not working?

Comment: @jainamshah - can you change data for see what data not working?

Comment: Thanks for the help but I will try.